# Array list containing latitude and longitude to be displayed on google maps

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I get a string (vertices) containing latitudes and longitudes of a polygon separated by commas. i convert it into an array and try to assign it to google maps to show the polygon. But when i hard code the values in the commented array below i get polygon on map but if i try to assign my array(polygoncoordinates) its not showing up. Can someone please tell me what mistake am i doing?

```
function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(23.9661, 76.6845),
                zoom: 7
            };
            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),            mapOptions);
            var val = vertices.split(',');            
            var polygonCoordinates = [];
            for (var i = 1; i<val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i] == "") {
                }
                else {                    
                    var temp;
                    temp = val[i].split(':');
                    var kk = temp[1].split(';');
                    var googleContent = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' + kk[0] + ', ' + kk[1] ')';   
                    polygonCoordinates.push(googleContent);
                }
            }

    //        var polygonCoordinates = [new google.maps.LatLng(23.9661, 76.6845),
    //new google.maps.LatLng(23.1605,81.7822),
    //new google.maps.LatLng(26.7848, 82.4853)
    //];

            var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: polygonCoordinates,
                strokeColor: 'black',
                strokeOpacity: 0.8,
                strokeWeight: 2,
                fillColor: 'black',
                fillOpacity: 0.35
            });
            bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
var googleContent = 'new google.maps.LatLng(' + kk[0] + ', ' + kk[1] ')';
polygonCoordinates.push(googleContent);
```

you are building an array of strings. `polygonCoordinates` should be an array of `LatLng`. You have to use:

```
var googleContent = new google.maps.LatLng(kk[0], kk[1]);   
polygonCoordinates.push(googleContent);
```